# write into a file with fprintf

Tags: c, string, dynamic-memory-allocation, c-strings, local-variables

I try to write into a file with this function.
When i call the function with this line the file remains empty:

```
if(argc-optind==0){
  char* line=readcli();
  printf("testline:%s\n",line); //WORKS
  line=replacet(line,t,countt(line));
  if(oFlag==1){
    writeinfile(line,oFileName);
  }else{
    printf("Expanded:%s\n",line);
  }
}
```

But if i call it like this it works:

```
char text[]={"test"};
char * textptr=text;
writeinfile(textptr,fp);

void writeinfile(char* line,char* file){
  FILE *f = fopen(file, "a");
  if (f == NULL){
    printf("Error opening file!\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  fprintf(f, "Some text: %s\n",line);
  fclose(f);
}
```

replaces tabs with spaces

```
char* replacet (char *text, int tabsize, int tabanz){
    int newsize=strlen(text)+tabsize*tabanz-tabanz;
    char newtext[newsize];//Wenn \t nu ein zeichen ist
    char* ptrnew=newtext;
    char* ptr=text;
    for(int i=0;i<strlen(text);i++,ptr++){
        if(text[i]=='\t'){
            for(int j=0;j<tabsize;j++){
                *ptrnew=' ';
                ptrnew++;
            }
        }else{
            *ptrnew=text[i];
            ptrnew++;
        }
    }
    char* newtextptr=newtext;
    return newtextptr;
}
```

Reads a line entered on the command line interface

```
char* readcli(){
    char *buffer;
    size_t bufsize = 64;
    size_t chars;
    buffer = (char *)malloc(bufsize * sizeof(char));
    if( buffer == NULL){
        perror("Error malloc");
    }    
    printf("Type something with Tabulators: ");
    chars = getline(&buffer,&bufsize,stdin);
    printf("%zu characters were read.\n",chars);
    return buffer;
}
```

Please help me i dont know how i could fix it.
Thank you

Comment: Dare to show us what `line=replacet(line,t,countt(line));` does? As this line seems to be the obvious difference between the two snippets.

Comment: Also, what is the value of `oFlag`?  Is `printf("Expanded:%s\n",line);` executed?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: what is `oflag`? what is `readcli()`?  what is `replacet()`?

Comment: @alk i edited my question an added replacet, it just replaces tabs with spaces, countt just counts how many tabs are in given line

Comment: @JohnnyMopp, oFlag just show if the output into a file option is set. and jes printf(...) works

Comment: @n.m. sorry :/ will do it next time

Comment: @Kevin What do you mean, next time? Why not this time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issue:

- Here

  ```
  char* replacet (char *text, int tabsize, int tabanz){
    int newsize=strlen(text)+tabsize*tabanz-tabanz;
    char newtext[newsize];//Wenn \t nu ein zeichen ist
    ...
    char* newtextptr=newtext;
    return newtextptr;  /* <-- HERE */
  ```

  the address of a local variable (`newtext`) is returned. The memory is valid only if inside the function.

  The moment the function returned the memory is free'ed autmagically. Accessing it after the function returned invokes the infamous Undefined Behaviour. Anything can happen from the moment on. Do not do this.
- The function `replacet()` misses to `0`-terminate the new C-"string".

To fix all this replace

```
  char newtext[newsize];
```

by

```
  char * newtext = malloc(newsize + 1); /* +1 for 0-terminator each
                                           c-"string" needs */
  if (NULL == newtext) /* Error checking is debugging for free. */
  {
    return NULL;
  }
```

Add the `0`-terminator before leaving:

```
  newtext[i] = '\0'; /* or just the equivalent: ... = 0; */
  char* newtextptr = newtext;
  return newtextptr;
}
```

Change the calling code from

```
  line=replacet(line,t,countt(line));
```

to

```
  {
    char * pctmp = replacet(line, t, countt(line));
    if (NULL == pctmp)
    {
      /* exit or do what error handling made sense */
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE); /* include stlib.h for the EXIT_* macros */
    }
    else
    {
      free(line);
      line = pctmp;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you :D 

    `char * pctmp =replacet(line,t,countt(line));`

so i have to use this new pointer because the the function frees the storage of my line variable?

Comment: "*the function frees the storage of my line variable*" no, as there is no free inside it. (doing so would be alternative way to code this) You need to do this. In my last snippet the code does this, but only if the function successfully allocated and returned the "new" memory. See `if (NULL == pctmp) { ... } else {... }`

Comment: "*have to use this new pointer*" because it holds your new data.

Comment: You cannot patch the existing string (`line`) as you by expanding the tabs you grow it. This you obviously were aware of.

Comment: In one of my previous comments this "*because it holds*" should read "because it points to"!